# How can I find the current in this BJT & op-amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, bjt, transfer-function

I have a background in EE but am very rusty.  I was given this as a problem to help me brush up on my skills. I'm supposed to solve for I3.

What I've come up with so far is that the positive terminal of the ideal op amp is a virtual ground and no current flows into it. Thus the current flowing through resistor R3 is I=V1/R3. Would I3 then be the sum of currents I1, I2, and I? What about the op amp output going into the BJT, do I have to account for that at all?

I was also asked what the transfer function of the diagram would be but I don't remember how to approach that at all.

[image]

For a little more context this is a question posed to me by my supervisor at an EE job I just started. I graduated 2 years ago but due to covid haven't been working and have gotten rusty on my technical skills. The diagram above is exactly what he sent me but a couple day prior we talked about the circuit and I drew what he showed me at that time and I'll attach it below. IQ supposedly goes from it's position in the second picture through and up the ground to where I2 is shown in the first picture. I recognize this isn't clear but this is what he gave me and I don't know how to approach it or what he's looking for in an answer.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a randomly drawn circuit. As drawn, I3 = 0. What is connected to I3? As drawn the output of the opamp will saturate to one of the power rails since there is no negative feedback.

Comment: @qrk Are you sure there's no negative feedback?  The ground symbol connects the negative input of the op-amp to the emitter of the BJT, and appears nowhere else.  Just because it's a ground symbol doesn't mean that the loop can't close through it.

Comment: @JohnD: We have to assume that V1 is referenced to ground. But I1 and I3 connect to open circuits. All we can say is that part of I2 is \$-\frac{V1}{R1+R2+R3}\$ and that \$V1\frac{R1+R2}{R1+R2+R3}\$ is being applied to the opamp. It's impossible to say what the opamp and the transistor are doing in response to that.

Comment: As far as a transfer function, what are we supposed to consider as "input" and "output"?

Comment: The opamp output is constrained to be 0.7V or below, with the emitter tied to ground like that. If ever the non-inverting input rises above ground, something's going to get hurt.

Comment: I edited the post to add a little more context. It's a question given to me by my supervisor at my new job and I don't really understand it like some of you guys seem to. I added a picture that shows more of I1 and I2 from a prior discussion he and I had.

With regards to the transfer function I believe V1 is intended to be the input and the output should be at the node of IL? He didn't really say.

Comment: It is a huge hint that this is intended to be a [tag:4-20mA] transmitter, a very common function in industrial controls. The general idea is that V1 will vary over some range (the output of some sort of sensor), and the output signal of the circuit is the current that flows from +PWR to -PWR. These key details were missing from your original diagram.

Comment: Sorry for not including that information sooner. 4-20mA is something he mentioned but as of yet I'm completely unfamiliar with. I understand now that V1 varies over some range where the low and high values equate to 4 and 20mA respectively, I guess I was getting too caught up with the op amp and BJT because that was all that was provided directly in the problem. Any idea on the transfer function? All he said was to find the transfer function of the circuit so I assume the output would be at the 4-20mA loop.

Answer (score 2):

*(See edits at bottom that take into account a point made by DaveTweed in comments below this answer. I'm leaving the initial post relatively intact.)*

Nice to see your interactions to questions. It doesn't occur often enough. Thanks.

What was done was something akin to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbWTIc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Before continuing, it's worth nothing that because \$V_m=V_p\$ it then follows that the voltage across \$R_s\$ is ever the same as the voltage across \$R_2\$. The current in \$R_1\$ must flow through \$R_2\$ and develop a voltage across it and this voltage difference must be the same as the voltage difference across \$R_s\$. Since the supply current has to be the sum of the current in \$R_2\$ and in \$R_s\$, you can work out that \$I_{_\text{SUPPLY}}=\frac{\frac{V_x}{R_1}\cdot R_2}{R_s}+\frac{V_x}{R_1}\$ or, in other words, that \$I_{_\text{SUPPLY}}=\frac{V_x}{R_1}\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_s}\right)\$.

So in this relatively simple case you don't need to do any "transfer function" work, if you don't want to do so.

Assuming you actually want to develop the transfer function, then you can just as well redraw the above as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6B4c2.png)</sup>

You are allowed to choose any convenient ground, yes? Well, that one is *convenient*, now!

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_m}{R_s}+\frac{V_m+V_x}{R_1}&=I_{_\text{SUPPLY}}+\frac{V_p}{R_1}
\\\\
\frac{V_p}{R_1}+\frac{V_p}{R_2} &=\frac{V_m+V_x}{R_1}
\\\\
V_m &= V_p
\end{align*}$$

Three equations, three unknowns: solvable. \$V_m=V_p=V_x\frac{R_2}{R_1}\$ and \$I_{_\text{SUPPLY}}=\frac{V_x}{R_1}\cdot \left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_s}\right)\$.

Same answer as before! Well, I guess that's good news.

Oh. The transfer function. Well, that's just a footnote, now: \$\frac{I_{_\text{SUPPLY}}}{V_x}=\frac{1}{R_1}\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_s}\right)\$. Not sure who cares by this time.

Note that what's happening is that the opamp and BJT are moving the internal ground reference around based upon \$V_x\$ and that \$V_x\$ itself is tethered to that virtual ground reference. You can set the ratio of currents between \$R_2\$ and \$R_s\$ per your preferences and this then allows you to set \$R_1\$ to a relatively large value, if you want, in order to minimize the current compliance required of \$V_x\$.

Anyway, that's it.

### Expansion

The above analysis was done using two different ground references, with the same results.

I know very little about the design of \$4-20\:\text{mA}\$ transmitters. But from DaveTweed's comments about interpreting your 2nd diagram, I suspect you were being asked about a "Type 2" transmitter that requires a minimum compliance voltage to operate. He points out that there is a quiescent current path shown, behaviorally, on your 2nd diagram. I think he's right, now that he pointed it out to me.

You can look at a [page by Dataforth on 4-20 mA](https://www.dataforth.com/4-20mA-transmitter.aspx) for a lot more than I know about these systems. (It's short, so that means I know very little.) Take a look at their description of a Type 2 transmitter there.

A Type 2 may draw a small amount of operating current from the (+) lead of the loop, so long as it returns that current back to the node at the top of \$R_s\$, where it is *measured* and within the loop of control.

Let's assume that there's a quiescent current used to power the Type 2 device. This current, \$I_q\$, includes the opamp (-) supply rail current [the (+) rail current splits into two parts, the BJT base current and the remainder that is the (-) rail current], and any currents otherwise required by the circuit. All of these must terminate at the node at the top of \$R_s\$, however they are sourced and/or used in the circuit. So \$I_q\$ represents this *bypass current* that is returned to that node.

Then:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUL68S.png)</sup>

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_m}{R_s}+\frac{V_m+V_x}{R_1}&=I_e + I_q+\frac{V_p}{R_1}
\\\\
\frac{V_p}{R_1}+\frac{V_p}{R_2} &=\frac{V_m+V_x}{R_1}
\\\\
V_m &= V_p
\end{align*}$$

From the above, we can readily find that \$I_e=\frac{V_x}{R_1}\cdot \left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_s}\right)-I_q\$. But then this is added to \$I_q\$ so that once again we have \$I_{_\text{SUPPLY}}=I_e+I_q=\frac{V_x}{R_1}\cdot \left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_s}\right)\$. Just so long as \$I_q\lt 4 \:\text{mA}\$, there's good reason to believe this will work well for the purposes intended.

I've actually enjoyed the opportunity that your question has afforded me. Both in learning more about \$4-20\:\text{mA}\$ systems (about which I knew very very little) and for the gently but wonderful educational comments by DaveTweed below this question. All in all, I've learned something myself and very much appreciate the process of learning about this here. Yet another reason this group is worth our time and effort. Just FYI and +1 for that!

Comment: Good analysis, except note that the power supply for the opamp/sensor/etc. is shown in the OP's second diagram, and its current also flows through Rs.

Comment: @DaveTweed I can't make much out of that second diagram on my phone. I don't think I made much of it, before, either. Too hard to read. I'll take another attempt at it tomorrow when I find a moment. Thanks!

Comment: @DaveTweed Okay. I still can't interpret that 2nd schematic well. Are they connecting the negative opamp rail into the "floating ground" there, so that the opamp output is always about one Vbe above it (not much margin)? That seems to be the only way to get all the current riding through. And it seems workable, though I've not tried spent much time thinking about it. I can't see a different possible reading than that, given your earlier comment. Let me know when you get a moment. I think my discussion and schematic should be repaired.

Comment: My interpretation is that the little box in the upper-right labeled "circuit load" represents whatever power the opamp and other components require to operate. There's a faint dotted line running from its ground symbol to the ground symbol at the top of Rs to emphasize that this is where its current is ending up. Note that this doesn't imply anything at all about the opamp rail voltages -- there could be a DC-DC converter in there that can supply arbitrary voltages.

Comment: @DaveTweed Ah. That makes sense but it also complicates the discussion. A simplification that keeps the discussion a little more concrete and less abstract would be to tie the (-) supply rail of the opamp to the floating ground. This will NOT work if the variable voltage is allowed to get too low. But with 4-20 mA that's less of an issue since 4 mA is the floor. So there probably will be enough overhead. Or do you see a problem simplifying it like that, that I may be missing?

Comment: No, that sounds fine. But I also see no problem with hand-waving away the issue of what the opamp rail voltages might actually be. It really doesn't matter, as long as we can assume that the output doesn't hit them.

Comment: To make it clear Dave Tweed interpreted the second image correctly. Thank you both for taking the time to look at this, share your thoughts, and have a discussion. I was really lost but you've helped me understand the circuit and more generally 4-20mA design.